# Function space where point evaluation is not continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, functions

Can someone give an example for a function space in which point evaluation $\delta_x$ is not a continuous functional?

The only example in this direction I know about is $L_2$, but this is not a space of functions but of equivalence classes of functions.

Thank you!

Comment: You can define the space of continuous functions on $[a,b]$ with the $L^2$ norm. That's a function space, and point evaluation is not continuous. You can do the same with the $L^p$ norm for any $1 \le p < \infty$.

Comment: @DisintegrationByParts I am not able to follow properly. Can please make it more rigorous or can you give me some hint such that I can make it rigorous? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If point evaluations were continuous for the continuous functions on $[a,b]$ with respect to the $L^2$ norm, then every sequence of such functions converging in the $L^2$ norm would converge pointwise everywhere. All you have to do is find a sequence of continuous functions on $[a,b]$ that converges in $L^2$, but does not converge pointwise everywhere.

Comment: If functions are taken instead of equivalence classes, then the $L^2$-norm is not really a norm since definiteness fails.